# Django User.authenticate() Behaving Funny

Tags: python, django, authentication

My users simply register in two stages(pages) through *signup* page:

1. Collect username, email and password - store these in my models (`myUsers`) and also to Django's `User` model for authentication and role assignment.
2. Collect user's interest which is added to `myUsers` object that was created in 1 and then directed to home page.

Now most of my **views** have `@login_required()` wrapper but users who just register and are directed to home don't have access to these views but old users do.

User logs in through *login* page:

```
sign_in = sign_in_form(request.POST or None)
if sign_in.is_valid():
    user_name = sign_in.cleaned_data['username']
    user_password = sign_in.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(username = user_name, password = user_password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
        else:
            #handle_this
```

The above code works fine and users have access to all **views** that are wrapped with `login_required`. But if I try `authenticate()` for registering users, they don't have access to **views** with `@login_required`:

```
sign_up = sign_up_form(request.POST or None)
    if sign_up.is_valid():
        user_name = sign_up.cleaned_data['username']
        user_email = sign_up.cleaned_data['email']
        user_password = sign_up.cleaned_data['password']
        #Save all these information to myUsers model and save same to User model.
        user = authenticate(username = user_name, password = user_password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                #Proceed to page two and then to home page after saving user's interest to myUsers model.
            else:
                #handle_this
```

Now if this user completes her signup process and the proceeds to home page tries to access **views** wrapped with `login_required` it throws:

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/mySite/user/yax/**

---

### Page not found (404)

**Request Method:   GET**
**Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/mySite/user/yax/**

**Using the URLconf defined in myProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:**

**^mySite/**

**The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.**

They will have to *log out* and *login* again to have everything work fine. How do I do this correctly to prevent this?

Comment: Can you show how u have processed  the sign-up ?